Can aggregate objects such as ARRECORD in Intact be retrieved using the API?
Can aggregate objects such as ARRECORD in Sage Intact be retrieved using the API?
I am trying to query the ARRECORD using api but it does not seem possible ..is there a way to retrieve this?
